# Checking if INSERT INTO statement was successful

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, insert

I am using a MS Access database as the backend of my VB.NET application. I am entering users details into the database using an INSERT INTO statement:

```
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & config("DatabasePath") & ";")
cn.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO blah blah blah...", cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Everything works, but I wanted to check if the data has actually been entered into the database. I have tried using:

```
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & config("DatabasePath") & ";")
cn.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO blah blah blah...", cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.Read() Then
    ' Blah
End If
```

but obviously the insert statement doesn't return anything so this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you have is the INSERT statement you can use the [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery%28VS.71%29.aspx) method which returns how many rows were affected.

Like this:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO blah blah...", cn)
rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If rowCount < 1 Then 
    ' Blah
```

You have to excuse me if the VB isn't correct, I didn't test it, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run a quick `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah blah blah` using the same key criteria as you used for the insert ?

Comment: This is what I thought of the first time. Problem is there are going to be more than one of the same rows, so unless I keep a count of the amount of dupelicate rows this isn't very feasable. Plus i'd like to minimise my database queries as much as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method, as the query doesn't return any result. The method returns an integer which is the number of rows affected.

```
Dim count As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```